# Route Windows 10 Updates through specific WAN

Tags: windows-10, routing, windows-update

I have a TP Link TL-R480T+ Load Balancing router connected to 2 WANs. I have setup policy routing such that some of my devices (given static IPs), got through faster, more expensive WAN2. I want to make it such that when Windows 10 updates run on these devices, they go through WAN1 only. How do I achieve this?

I could have set up static routing, but that requires IP addresses and I don't believe the IPs of Windows Update servers would be fixed (or a small list).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
you shall force the all MS Windows Update URLs connections to be routed through your preferred WAN. Refer to the URL list you can find here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/en-en/library/bb693717.aspx

**Solution 2:**
Install a local WSUS server on Windows Server 2012R2 and force this machine to work with your preferred WAN. Other clients (after the proper configuration through GPO or registry keys) will connect to WSUS server to download the updates.

Comment: Thanks. Solution 2 is out of reach as a Win Server license is way off our budget. The problem with Solution 1 would be that I don't see a way to route by URL on my router; The static routes require IPs and I don't think these IPs will be static